# How to maintain foreign key relationship in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have two classes and I want to have a one to many relation between them, for e.g.:

```
Home(id<int>, rooms<string>)

Vehicle(id<int>, home_id<int>, name<string>)
```

I need to have a relation between `Home` and `Vehicle` class using `Home.id` and `vehicle.home_id`.

Please suggest any example which I can use here for CURD operation to implement REST service.

Comment: look up hibernate @JoinColumn annotation, it's really basic stuff you'll find tutorial everywhere

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have a relation between `Home` and `Vehicle` class using `Home.id`
>   and `vehicle.home_id`.

Your entities should look like this :

**Vehicle Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "vehicle", catalog = "bd_name", schema = "schema_name")
@XmlRootElement
public class Vehicle implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @JoinColumn(name = "home_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private Home homeId;

    //constructor getter & setters

}
```

**Home Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "home", catalog = "bd_name", schema = "schema_name")
@XmlRootElement
public class Home implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name = "room")
    private Character room;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "homeId")
    private List<Vehicle> vehicleList;

    //constructor getter & setters
}
```

Comment: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [com.kumar.persistence.pojo.Vehicle] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
 ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='may not be null', propertyPath=account, rootBeanClass=class com.kumar.persistence.pojo.Vehicle, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
] got this error while persits.